# Why moment.weekdays() returns days starting with Sunday when I specified that first day is Monday?

Tags: momentjs

I set the locale to `'ro'` and now weekdays are in romanian.
But, I also set the

```js
week : {
    dow : 1
}
```

and `moment.weekdays()` returns days as in `'en'` starting with Sunday. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `moment.weekdays(true);`

As the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/) states:

> As of **2.13.0** you can pass a bool as the first parameter of the weekday functions. If true, the weekdays will be returned in locale specific order. For instance, in the Arabic locale, Saturday is the first day of the week

Here a live example:

```js
moment.locale('ro');
// duminică to sâmbătă
console.log(moment.weekdays());
// locale aware: luni to duminică
console.log(moment.weekdays(true));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

I did a dirty solution for my weekday's list!

```
const weekDays = [...weekdaysShort().slice(1), weekdaysShort()[0]];
```

output: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]

Comment: You should never do such a thing when a proper solution is available.